# how to design some part of paragraph in a special format, css, html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design some word inside the paragraph in a special format. But it said to me than inside the `<p>` tag I cant use the tags `<bank1>` and `<bank2>` that i have created. I dont want to close the `<p>` tag because I dont want to go into a new line, but i want to stay inside the paragraph. Can anyone help me please... Thanks in advance
This is the html line:

```
<p class="title">Welcome to <bank1>TACROX </bank1> <bank2> Bank </bank2>!</p>
```

And this is the css part

```
bank1 {
    font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #d9531e;
}

bank2 {
    font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
    color: #22242b;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Try using <span> with a different classes

Comment: A span would be your best bet.

Comment: change `bank1` and `bank2` to the classes and use `span` tag: `<span class="bank1">TACROX </span>`

Comment: Thanks a lot..It function

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<p class="title">Welcome to <span class="bank1">TACROX</span> <span class="bank2">Bank</span>!</p>
```

And CSS:

```
.bank1 {
    font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #d9531e;
}
.bank2 {
    font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
    color: #22242b;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

There's no such thing as a `bank1` or `bank2` element, so you could use `span`s with a specified `class`. You can't just make your own elements.

Also, since there are similarities between the two, you could remove some redundancy:

```
.bank1, .bank2 {
    font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.bank1
    color: #d9531e;
}
.bank2 {
    color: #22242b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a span class:

```
<p class="title">Welcome to <span class="bank1">TACROX </span> <span class="bank2"> Bank </span>!</p>
```

And the CSS:

```
.bank1{font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
      font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #d9531e;}
.bank2{font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
    color: #22242b;
    font-size: 1.2em;}
```

You can find more information about span tags here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a span, you can't create random elements.

### CSS

```
#bank1{
  font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #d9531e;
}
#bank2{
  font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", serif;
  color: #22242b;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

### HTML

```
<p class="title">Welcome to <span id="bank1">TACROX </span> <span id="bank2"> Bank </span>!</p>
```

Comment: probably shouldn't use IDs - what if you need to reuse the same style?

Comment: If he reuses the styles yes, in the example there are two unique elements. Going off what is not what could be.